# Right aligned control labels in form-horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to do a two-column form that behaves as follows with Twitter Bootstrap (3.2.0):

- on extra-small (xs) screens, the second column is shown below the first column, control labels are shown above the input fields
- on small (sm) screens, the two columns are shown beside each other, control labels are shown above the input fields
- one medium (md) screens, the two columns are shown beside each other, control labels are horizontally aligned with their input fields

My code below (also at http://jsfiddle.net/mieckert/pfnbxbbo/) works with one issue:  on small screens, the control labels are shown above their input fields, but they are right aligned (instead of proper left alignment).

The cause of this is that bootstrap in `forms.less` switches on right alignment based on a media query:

```
form-horizontal {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .control-label {
      text-align: right;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding-top: (@padding-base-vertical + 1); // Default padding plus a border
    }
  }
```

Is there a way I can teach bootstrap to use a different media query (say for `@screen-md-min`) without having to modify the bootstrap source itself, i.e., by overriding it in another less file that has an `@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"`?  Especially is it possible to do this in a way that I'm not actually querying the screen width but rather the width of the current column?  (Otherwise it would affect other forms that have a single column layout and still align horizontally as well.)  Or are there any other, better ways to achieve the responsive behavior I described?

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">First name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">Last name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">Phone number</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">Remarks</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the class `left-label` to each of your labels in the form above, and then use this CSS to left-align the text:

```
label.col-sm-12.left-label {
        text-align: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/43o7r5cj/).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem where I wanted labels to appear above the input for xs screen size via col-xs-12.  I came up with the following media query and use of !important to override the text-align right that bootstrap applied:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    label.col-xs-12 {
      text-align: left !important;
    }
}
```